# Issue with loading dynamic content to the detail page, using employee directory

Tags: 2sxc

I'm trying to set up a employee directory using the app with the same name. The first item works fine, the list view links to the url **/employee/[Content:EntityId]** and the detail shows the rest of the information of the item. However when I add additional items to the list view, the link works fine, but the content shown in the details is still that of the first item.

> The site is running on DNN 8.0.4 and 2sxc 9.32.1

I've tried editing the link to the detail page, edit either template etc. however nothing I try seems to solve the issue.

I left the list template as much "as is" as possible:

```
 <a class="app-empdir-link" href="[Tab:FullUrl]/employee/[Content:EntityId]">
    <h2>[Content:Title]</h2>
 </a>
```

And the detail page simply uses the [Content: ] tokens aswel.

However all 'Content' tokens in the detail page seem to only show the content of the first item in the list and not the one that was selected in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing you must know is that the templates just show the items they get. So the question is - what determines what they get?

Basically each module has zero, one or more items, and without additional configuration, it's simply the items added by the user.

The additional configuration is as follows: you must create a simple query (visual query) which finds an item based on the value in the URL. This is done in the `Query` tab in the app management. I have to leave in a few minutes so I can't point you to a link, but if you research `visual query 2sxc` you should quickly find some examples.

Once you have the query and you've tested it (you can configure test values like `[QueryString:employee]=245` in the query for testing it), then tell your details-view to use that query, and you're good to go.

Here some links - but they are not 100% what you need - to get started:

1. https://2sxc.org/en/Learn/Visual-Query-Designer
2. https://2sxc.org/en/blog/tag/visual-query-designer